# Affine hull of the intersection of two convex sets

Tags: convex-analysis, affine-geometry

Is it true that the affine hull of the intersection of two convex sets is the intersection of the affine hulls of these sets? Where the intersection of the two convex sets is non empty?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No. Counterexample: consider {0} and {1}.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the affine hull of sets...my understanding is that in R2, the span of a vector v is the line through the origin, is aff(v) just the vector itself? So aren't aff({0}) and aff({1}) just {0} and {1}? In which case their intersection is empty?

Comment: Sorry I also forgot to mention that the intersection of the two convex sets is non empty. I've added that to my question now. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I just thought of something - is this correct? Consider R2, let C1=[0,1]^2, C2= line with intercept 1, slope 1. Then aff(C1)=R2, aff(C2)=C2, their intersection is C2, whilst the affine hull of the intersection of C1 and C2 is the affine hull of the singleton (0,1) which is (0,1)?

Comment: Yes, the affine hull of a singleton set is just the set itself. So the intersection is empty.

Comment: I like your counterexample (C1 and C2). Looks like you have answered your own question!

Comment: Your answer motivated my example. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Would it be true if we now assume that their relative interiors have a nonempty intersection?

Answer (score 0):

Just to give a counterexample where the intersection of $C_1$ and $C_2$
is nonempty, you can consider the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}$ and the convex sets $C_1=[0,1]$, and $C_2=[1,2]$.

In this case, we have $\text{aff}(C_1)=\text{aff}(C_2)=\mathbb{R}$. Thus, $\text{aff}(C_1)\cap\text{aff}(C_2)=\mathbb{R}$. On the other hand $C_1\cap C_2=\{1\}$ and $\text{aff}(\{1\})=\{1\}$.